# Storing values from a file into array according to some multiple split() criteria

Tags: java, string, file-handling

This is the file from where i am reading:

```
abc.txt
1,Arjun,12,GhandiNagar,Pune,411020
2,Deep,8,M.G.Road,Mumbai,411032
3,Deep,3,F.C.Road,Pune,411032
```

Now how do I store individual content in a String array.
I have used

```
String content="";
while(line=br.readLine()!=null)
{
   content=line+content;
}
String x[]=content.split(",");
```

But this is splitting according to "," as a result of which the last content of every line become 411020'2'/ 411032'3'. 
So how do i separate them and store in an array like

`x[0]=1,x[1]=Arjun,x[2]=12,x[3]=GhandiNagar,x[4]=Pune,x[5]=411020,x[6]=2,etc..?`

Comment: Don't concatenate strings. Use a StringBuffer!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a comma after the line is added to the content:

```
content = line + "," + content;
```

By the way, this effectively reverses the order of the lines in your file. If you don't want this to happen do this:

```
content = content + "," + line;
```

But using string concatenation (which is what you are doing) is best avoided (poor performance) by using a StringBuilder/StringBuffer (better performance)

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   content.append(line);
   content.append(",");
}

String[] x = content.toString().split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
String x[]=line.split(",");
```

within your while block. The split by "," will ignore line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String x[] = line.split(",|\\r?\\n");
```

This code splits line with multiple delimiters. It splits line at every "," AND every "\n", which represents the end of a line in a text file. `|` is the regex OR operator.